# SwiftUI @Binding in subview how I can observe changes (aka didSet) from parent

Tags: binding, swiftui, didset

I would like to observe changes to **@Binding** property in subview. But there didSet/willSet is not called (it is called only if I change this variable from current view, but if change is from outside view then this handlers are not executed)

I want to execute some code when

```
 @Binding var selectedElement: Int
```

is changed from parent view.

Then I want to recalculate xOffset state property

```
 @State var xOffset: CGFloat = 0
```

The calculation should increment current xOffset value like:

```
self.xOffset += self.contentSize.width/2 - (self.rects[i].minX + self.rects[i].width/2)
```

But I stack in this place.

Comment: just use @Binding in the subview and not State.

Comment: I am using binding but setting xOffset is subview specific I do not want to move this to parent and all logic belonging to child move also to parent

Comment: @MichałZiobro did you ever find out? Thanks!